# Propeller effect on the L/D of an aircraft (Pusher Propeller configuration)

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, propeller, propulsion

I recently performed an aerodynamic analysis of a fixed-wing UAV with a pusher propeller configuration. I found out that the L/D reduced by about 15% when compared to the body alone without propeller. I am investigating methods to mitigate this problem.

The following are some details about the aircraft,
Wing Span = 2.5 m

Fuselage length = 2 m

MTOW = 25 kgs

Tandem wing configuration. The following image is a representative image.

Courtesy: Raytheon Coyote

[image: Tandem wing UAV]

Any suggestions will really be helpful.

Comment: With a spinning propeller, or propeller at standstill?

Comment: Please explain how you measured that L/D reduction. Was the propeller spinning or fixed? How did the end of the aircraft look like initially, without the prop?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fair in the tail with a carbon fibre fairing/spinner such that the prop folds back and nests into it.  Like below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @John K. I have incorporating such a fairing mechanism at the rear portion and the above problem I mentioned is still persistent. Are there any other methods to decrease the negative impact of the propeller?

Comment: The only other thing that might help is the extend the spinner in a way that lets the blades lie completely flush in the spinner profile when folded.

Comment: Noted. Will try to push that to the greatest extent possible.